# Can Australians travel in certain Schengen countries for 90 days each?

Tags: visas, schengen, australia, australian-citizens, 90-180-visa-rules

I was recently informed by the Dutch immigration department that Australian and New Zealand citizens can travel to a large number of countries within Europe for 90 days each, essentially bypassing the 90 day Shengen limit.
They said that the bilateral visa waiver agreements ([link here](http://www.austlii.edu.au/au/other/dfat/treaties/1951/4.html)) allowed for this in Austria, Belgium, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Iceland, Italy, Luxembourg, The Netherlands, Norway, Portugal, Spain, Sweden and Switzerland.

Is this information correct? I am skeptical because I can't find any other information about this online, however they were adamant that this was the case and sent me an email with these details to give me proof.

Should I trust this information?

Edit: This is a different question to the "duplicate" linked as that question does not concern Australia, which obviously has different visa agreements to other countries.

Edit 2: I also found this website which seems to essentially confirm the information from the Dutch immigration department https://thefreedominitiative.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/unlimited-visa-in-europe-for-free-maybe/

Comment: I doubt that a Dutch-Australian agreement signed some thirty years before Schengen agreement can cover stay duration in, say, Sweden. I think it was a miscommunication.

Comment: It's there in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Australian_citizens#Additional_rules) but only lists 6 countries.

Comment: The linked question doesn't contain the information for Australia or much of anything really. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @mkennedy the linked question is a broad canonical about all nationalities, not just Australia. Feel free to expand the community wiki answer there

Comment: To OP: the linked question is *precisely* what you need. But unfortunately we don't have a solid answer for all the Schengen countries yet.